# Confusion with node.js VS apache HTTPD

Tags: multithreading, node.js

I am total confused with the difference between node and thread. Now In httpd documentation they say that they create a main process which creates a child process which in turn maintains a fixed number of threads.

A thread pool works like Apache’s pre-forking. The threads are created en
block at the program start, and then the work load is distributed evenly.
When there are more connections than threads, the new connections have
to wait. But on the plus side, you save the cost for the thread creation.

Now my doubt here is since threads can run with shared memory why cant any number of threads be created?

When it comes to node. Node is completely event-driven. Basically the server consists of one thread processing one event after another. A new request coming in is one kind of event. The server starts processing it and when there is a blocking IO operation, it does not wait until it completes and instead registers a callback function. The server then immediately starts to process another event (maybe another request). When the IO operation is finished, that is another kind of event, and the server will process it (i.e. continue working on the request) by executing the callback as soon as it has time.

Now if the node does not create a new thread then how can it accept a new request.

Comment: http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the blog [Understanding the node.js event loop](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/)

**Node.js keeps a single thread for your code…**

It really is a single thread running: you can’t do any parallel code execution; doing a “sleep” for example will block the server for one second:

Source code

```
while(new Date().getTime() < now + 1000) {
   // do nothing
}
```

So while that code is running, node.js will not respond to any other requests from clients, since it only has one thread for executing your code. Or if you would have some CPU -intensive code, say, for resizing images, that would still block all other requests.

Check the blog for more details. It is explaining the the event loop in detail.

**EDIT**

Check this, a nice reference
[Multi-Process Node.js: Motivations, Challenges and Solutions](http://www.infoq.com/articles/multi-core-node-js/)

Comment: lets say two request come at the same time then which one will be proceed in node.js

Comment: The first one. There can't exist "two things at the same time" in computing, it's not quantum physics where such a concept could exist.

Comment: To complete @N.B's answer, Node will process the first request, allocating its only computing thread on it. But on the first asynchronous call (eg. a database lookup or HTTP request), it will process the next event on the event loop, which is likely to be your second request.

Comment: @TwoThe - they don't. Each does its own thing. That's not one entity doing two things at once. But if you think it's doing it, then feel free to explain how your two cores can push two different pieces of information into the very same memory block.

Comment: Thank you i got the answers to all my questions in the link

Comment: They actually have a local copy of that memory block inside their cache. But I think you are over-interpreting the "same time" a bit. Yes data cannot be written to singular memory cells "at the same time", but the calculation that happens before - which is the actual important part - does happen "at the same time".

Comment: @TwoThe - when it comes to *servers* such as Node, it can't physically accept two connections at the same time, there will always be one than another. I don't think we should debate this at all. Now, as for performing two instructions on two different processors - yes, it happens at the same time but that's not the problem proposed with the main question - what happens when node accepts two requests at the same time - it doesn't do that because it can't.

Comment: Neither of his questions ask about "same time" execution or network details. So yes I agree: this is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with JavaScript is, that it is notoriously single-threaded. Therefore threading can't *simply* exist (there are some complex solutions, but those tend to be very complex in the end). Node.js uses a non-blocking IO approach to circumvent this restriction, which is in the end a smart use of single-threading by avoiding any blocking and having those task frequently pause for a second to let others do a bit of work as well. Similar to the old single-core multi-tasking emulation in Windows 95-ME.

Now the big problem is: should any of those processing threads ever be put on hold, then the entire server is put on hold. This is not an issue as long as you work small-scale, but this is an absolute no-go for a big server environment. In addition modern servers have 8 and more cores, and keeping 7 of those idle is a big waste of hardware.

HTTPD in the worker configuration spawns one fork of itself (the original executable acts as a backup just in case) and then spawns threads based on the configured value. It can in theory run 1000ands of threads simultaneously, but if your CPU only has 8 cores, no more than 8 of those threads can be processed at a single time - obviously. So the other 992 threads need to wait, and this can - depending on the task - even cause clients to run into a time-out, because they had to wait over 30 seconds.

How many threads a are a good value primarily depends on what your threads do. If they never block, but spend 100% of the time on actually solving the problem, then about cores * 2 is a good value for httpd, because of the core-limitation as above. If your threads block a lot (disk access, tcp communication), then a higher or much higher value might result in a better throughput. In the end the only way to find out is to launch test-data against the server and measure the throughput in various configurations.

Modern web servers however (httpd is centuries old) combine those two approaches: a non-blocking single receiver thread, that reads the data and then distributes it to available threads. This has the benefit that IO operations are lightning fast (even faster than node.js if the code is native code), but still all cores can be used simultaneously. Java can do this via [NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) (new IO) and then distribute [Runnables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) to [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).